# How to handle HTTP 204 No Content Response in Spring

Tags: java, spring-webclient

From my spring boot app I am making multiple calls to an API search service using the Spring Web Client. This is required due to pagination and multiple search params that cannot be used together.

When making calls with certain params I am getting HTTP 204 No Content, which is completely normal and expected. However this is causing an issue with decoding the body to my Response object

I am attempting to handle the 204 status in a filter but what I am doing seems a bit wonky and wondering how this should be handled. I am new to the reactive style but want to avoid using the deprecated RestTemplate style.

```
                    .builder()
                    .filter(WebClientFilter.handleError())
                    .filter(responseFilter)
                    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().followRedirect(true)))
                    ... default header stuff ommitted ...
                    .build().post().uri(searchServiceUrl)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(createsearchRequest()))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(SearchResponse.class)
                    .block();
```

Here is where I am filtering for the 204 and returning a newly constructed Response with my empty Dto. This just seems wrong that I am replacing the response from the server with my own, but if I do not do this the WebClient returns null causing other issues.

```
private static Mono<ClientResponse> exchangeFilterResponseProcessor(ClientResponse response) {
        HttpStatus status = response.statusCode();
        if (HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.equals(status)) {
            return response.bodyToMono(String.class).flatMap(body ->  {
                    log.info("Body is {}" , body);
                ClientResponse emptyResponse = ClientResponse.create(HttpStatus.OK)
                        .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
                        .body(new SearchResponse().toString())
                        .build();
            return Mono.just(emptyResponse);
            });
        }
        return Mono.just(response);
    }
```

Should I refactor the code to just allow the null response and deal with it that way vs trying to do it in the code above?